# Showing dialog on map click

Tags: angularjs, openlayers-3

I have an ol3 map element from the Openlayers Directive that I want to show an add marker dialog on when clicked. When you click the map it is registering the position but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.showAddMarker (map.controller.js:60)
    at map.controller.js:54
    at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$evaL
    ...
```

I am trying to use [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.dialog) example for mdDialog. My code to open the dialog is in the controller for the map.

```
angular.module('comhubApp')
//Fixed the initial import error
.controller('MapCtrl', [ '$scope', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        windsor: { 
            lat: 42.300095327770569,
          lon: -83.02625377869369,
          zoom: 13
        },
        center: {
            lat: 54.063408,
          lon: -101.910305,
            zoom: 3
        },
        defaults: {
    events: {
        map: [ 'singleclick', 'pointermove' ]
    }
  },
  mouseposition: {},
  mouseclickposition: {},
  projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    });

$scope.$on('openlayers.map.singleclick', function(event, data) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        if ($scope.projection === data.projection) {
            $scope.mouseclickposition = data.coord;
        } else {
            var p = ol.proj.transform([ data.coord[0], data.coord[1] ],     data.projection, $scope.projection);
            $scope.mouseclickposition = {
                lat: p[1],
                lon: p[0],
                projection: $scope.projection
            }
//THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEMS STARt :(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(
            $scope.showAddMarker();
        }
    });
});

 $scope.showAddMarker = function()  {
  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: AddMarkerCtrl,
    // templateUrl: '../addMarker',
    template: '<md-dialog><add-marker></add-marker></md-dialog>',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    locals: {point: $scope.mouseclickposition }
  });
  // .then(function(answer) {
  //   $scope.alert = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
  // }, function() {
  //   $scope.alert = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
  // });
};

function AddMarkerCtrl($scope, $mdDialog) {

$scope.closeDialog = function() {
  // Easily hides most recent dialog shown...
  // no specific instance reference is needed.
  $mdDialog.hide();
};
```

}

Can I use a controller for the dialog inside the map controller the way I am here? It seems like bad form but I am not sure how to separate it. I was setting up the addMarker html as a directive but I am thinking that may be wrong as well or at least implemented wrong. I am super new to angularjs and the lot. If you need to see other code please let me know.

Comment: The problem is this line: `$mdDialog.show` At that point in your code, the `$mdDialog` variable does not exist. Did you inject it into the controller?

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is there twice. once in the map controller and also in that addMarkerCtrl..
 .controller('MapCtrl', [ '$scope', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {

Comment: Unless that's a typo, you haven't injected it. It should be `.controller('MapCtrl', [ '$scope', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {`

Comment: thanks! I missed that. I now have a shiny new error to work on. :S

Comment: No problem. I'm going to add it as an answer for future visitors. Feel free to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with injecting the `$mdDialog`.

This is what it was:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', [ '$scope', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
```

And this is the fix:

```
.controller('MapCtrl', [ '$scope', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
```